# Storage account API returns null

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

i am trying to retrieve retail prices of azure storage i am following this document.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices#api-endpoint

In this document, I can able to find only virtual machine, compute, etc. but when I try to use the Retail Rates Prices API to get retail prices of storage account, as per above document information I made some changes I am getting response as null.

API endpoint as `https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices`

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEPzM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I am getting the same null value:

***You can make use of below ApI endpoint for storage account as below:***

```
https://prices.azure.com/api/retail/prices?api-version=2021-10-01-preview&$filter=serviceFamily eq 'Storage'
```

when I try to pass `filter=serviceFamily eq 'Storage'` I can able to get retail prices of azure storage successfully.

[image]